# What is a common name for the resulting function?

Tags: statistics, functions, regression, regression-analysis

Consider the following population regression model:

$$y_{i} = \beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i} + \epsilon _{i},$$

where $i=1,...,n$. Assume $\epsilon \sim iid$, with the pdf in equation: $f(\epsilon ) = \alpha \epsilon$ for $0\leq \epsilon \leq 1$.

For $n=4$, we have $f(\epsilon _{1},\epsilon _{2},\epsilon _{3},\epsilon _{4}) = f_{1}(\epsilon _{1}) f_{2}(\epsilon _{2}) f_{3}(\epsilon _{3}) f_{4}(\epsilon _{4}) = \alpha \prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i}$. This is because of no autocorrelation in errors.

Now we substitute $f(\epsilon _{1},\epsilon _{2},\epsilon _{3},\epsilon _{4})$ in the regression model and obtain

$$y_{i} = \beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}+\prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i}$$.

Taking the natural logs, we obtain

$$ln(y_{i}) = ln(\beta _{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}+\prod _{i=1}^{4} \epsilon _{i})$$.

What is a common name for the resulting function?

I am guessing it is the maximum log likelihood function. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are wrong it have nothing common with log likelihood  function. Moreover the model has defects, because you do not guarantee that $y_i>0$ otherwise you cannot make a log.

Comment: The instructor told me to take the natural logs of the function. What's the function called then if it is not the log likelihood function?

Comment: To get log likelihood function you have to take log of LIKELIHOOD function. Likelihood is a product of $f_i$ which is not what you wrote but $\prod f(y_i-\beta_1-\beta_2 x_i)$